# Calling Javascript Validation Methods on ASP.NET MVC 2 View's form submitting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How to invoke Form Validation Javascript methods before submitting ASP.NET MVC view?

Comment: Found many answers regarding my Query but all of them are using MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js. I am using Jquery version 1.4.4 .. Dont know if it is compatible with MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js...I cannt find Form.Validate() method .. it is coming out to be null and giving me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is guide to client side validation.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

and when you complete the file check what is generated for you. this will be nice start for you.

hope this helps.

Comment: Explanation given in above link also uses  MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js so it is not going to be useful for me ....

Comment: This has all the relevant java script in there generated and this could be base on how to do this... check following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456/mvc-net-jquery-validation